# How to map values of a column to other rows in the same column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :
+--+----+
|id|cluster|
+--+----+
| 12345|A|
| 67890|A|
| 45678|A|
| 98765|A|
| 12321|A|
| 98789|A|
+--+----+

How can i use pandas to return each value as a recommendation for each id?
desired output:

+--+-------+--------------+
|id|cluster|recommendation|
+--+-------+--------------+
| 12345|A|67890
| 12345|A|45678
| 12345|A|98765
| 12345|A|12321
| 12345|A|98789
| 67890|A|12345
| 67890|A|45678
| 67890|A|98765
| 67890|A|12321
| 67890|A|98789
...
| 98789|A|12321
+--+-------+--------------+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a column of lists and `explode`:

```
df['recommendation'] = pd.Series([list(df['id'])]*len(df))
df = df.explode('recommendation').query('id != recommendation')
```

*NB. add `reset_index(drop=True)` if needed to have a non duplicate index*

output:

```
      id cluster recommendation
0  12345       A          67890
0  12345       A          45678
0  12345       A          98765
0  12345       A          12321
0  12345       A          98789
1  67890       A          12345
...
4  12321       A          98789
5  98789       A          12345
5  98789       A          67890
5  98789       A          45678
5  98789       A          98765
5  98789       A          12321
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cross join with `df` and `id` column of `df` using [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).  Filter out same `id` and rename the column labels, as follows:

```
(df.merge(df[['id']].rename({'id': 'recommendation'}, axis=1), how='cross')
   .query('id != recommendation')
)
```

or, if your Pandas version is older than 1.2.0 (released on December 2020) and does not support cross join (merge with `how='cross'`), you can use:

```
(df.assign(key=1).merge(df[['id']].rename({'id': 'recommendation'}, axis=1).assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
   .query('id != recommendation')
)
```

**Result:**

```
       id cluster  recommendation
1   12345       A           67890
2   12345       A           45678
3   12345       A           98765
4   12345       A           12321
5   12345       A           98789
6   67890       A           12345
8   67890       A           45678
9   67890       A           98765
10  67890       A           12321
11  67890       A           98789
12  45678       A           12345
13  45678       A           67890
15  45678       A           98765
16  45678       A           12321
17  45678       A           98789
18  98765       A           12345
19  98765       A           67890
20  98765       A           45678
22  98765       A           12321
23  98765       A           98789
24  12321       A           12345
25  12321       A           67890
26  12321       A           45678
27  12321       A           98765
29  12321       A           98789
30  98789       A           12345
31  98789       A           67890
32  98789       A           45678
33  98789       A           98765
34  98789       A           12321
```